# Leads not created using wordpress plugins

Tags: integration, website-integration, wordpress

I am using Wordpress plugins "Contact Form 7" and "Forms: 3rd-Party Integration" to send leads to Salesforce. It has all been working up until 2 months ago. Now the emails/notifications are working but leads aren't created in Salesforce. 
Was there something that I need to change in wordpress plugins for recent changes in Salesforce?
I have also tried WordPress-to-Lead for Salesforce CRM also with out success.

Comment: Validation rules, Filtered Lookup values, and triggers are all admin-defined features that could prevent leads from being created. Are the emails sent from WP or salesforce?

Answer (score 2):

Is the submission URL up-to-date? About two months ago Salesforce changed the Web-to-Lead endpoint urls ( https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Updating-the-Web-to-Case-and-Web-to-Lead-Endpoint-URL&language=en_US&type=1 )

In WordPress, Under Contact>Third Party Services > Open the service and make sure the submission url points to "https://webto.salesforce.com/ser...." and not "https://www.salesforce.com/ser..."

Comment: Would not have been the issue in 2016 when the question was posted, but a good answer if this question turns up in search now.